# AngularJS show loader on every page

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a loader that will show on every page and fade out when all the content is loaded. Here is my code so far:

```
<div id="loader-wrapper" data-loader-drct data-ng-hide="hidden">
        <div id="loader"></div>

        <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
        <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
</div><!--end loader-wrapper-->
```

```
app.directive('loaderDrct', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
                    var hide = false;
                    scope.hidden = hide;

                    scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
                        hide = true;
                        scope.hidden = hide;
                    });
                });
            }
        }
}]);
```

When I execute this code, the loader is hiding (with some CSS added), but when I go to another page, the loader is not shown again. The `ng-hide` class is still there, which means that this directive has already been executed and did not refresh after going to the new page.

How can I make the loader show and hide on every page?

Comment: try shifting your hiding code in the controller in the pages, and just specify template HTML in directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found a solution made by michael. The problem is that the templates are loaded and the browser has no time to make the changes visible . You can find the full answer here: [Angular js - show/hide loading gif every new route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512893/angular-js-show-hide-loading-gif-every-new-route)

Answer (score 0):

For load while upload/download files

Add in **index.html**

```
<div id="loading_wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
</div>
```

And Add in **controller.js**

```
var $loadingWrapper = angular.element('#loading_wrapper');
```

Note: Make sure whether font-awesome css files installed or not. Otherwise, you can use simply bootstrap components.