# Angular2 access variables from another component

Tags: variables, events, binding, angular

Tried EventEmitter but no chance and so little documentation... Any help appreciated

I have a component called sidebar and another one called header, when you click on a button from the header, it should hide the sidebar... How would you achieve this in angular2 ?

thanks

Comment: you should create a service for the sidebar and bootstrap it, then inject it in any component and alter the properties through the service, [here is an almost similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069609/show-loading-screen-when-navigating-between-routes-in-angular-2/37070282#37070282)

Answer (score 7):

This is pretty easy with a Service you share between your Components.

For instance a `SidebarService`:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class SidebarService {
  showSidebar: boolean = true;

  toggleSidebar() {
    this.showSidebar = !this.showSidebar;
  }
}
```

In your sidebar component just put a `*ngIf` with the `showSidebar` variable from the `SidebarService`. Also don't forget to add the service in the constructor.

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar',
  template: `
      <div *ngIf="_sidebarService.showSidebar">This is the sidebar</div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class SidebarComponent {
  constructor(private _sidebarService: SidebarService) {

  }
}
```

In the component, where you want to handle the toggling of the sidebar also inject the `SidebarService` and add the `click` event with the service method.

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="_sidebarService.toggleSidebar()">Toggle Sidebar</button>
      <sidebar></sidebar>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [SidebarComponent]
})
export class App {
  constructor(private _sidebarService: SidebarService) {

  }
}
```

Don't forget to add the `SidebarService` to the providers in your bootstrap:

```ts
bootstrap(App, [SidebarService])
```

---

> [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ywc1Yl8sbfppGiHCzzX5?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: Thanks for the demo, it's works but I can't import the sidebar in the header. Both are imported by the AppComponent and I would like to keep things separated. Do you have any other solution ?

Comment: You can do it however you wish, it all revolves around the `SidebarService`, because that's how you save and change the state of the sidebar. The example was only to show how it works theoretically.