# How to implement spinner in angular2 and spinner hiding is possible in angular2?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have some delay on image loading time that time I want show a spinner and after image loading time that spinner should hide. What is the correct way to implement this in angular 2 platform.

```
        <div id='panId' class="container-fluid" >
```

This is the images loading,

```
            <img name="imageName1" mouseWheel style.width="{{imgWidth}}" (mouseWheelUp)="mouseWheelUpFunc($event)" (mouseWheelDown)="mouseWheelDownFunc()" 

                *ngIf="showImage" id="mainImage" src="{{imageVisible ? droppedImage: firtsImageToBind}}" class="imagepics mg-image "

                alt="loading..." />


            <img  name="imageName2" id="mainImage" mouseWheel style.width="{{imgWidth}}" (mouseWheelUp)="mouseWheelUpFunc($event)"

                (mouseWheelDown)="mouseWheelDownFunc()" class="mg-image " *ngIf="zoomImageVisible" src="{{zoomedImage}}">
        </div>


</div>
```

Comment: There are several questions on SO discussing the use of spinners/loading indicators in Angular2 e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144655/angular-2-loader-on-each-http-request).  See if those can point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

take a look at PrimeNG they have spinner and it's open source so you can just use it.

http://primefaces.org/primeng

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/tree/master/components/spinner

Comment: Can I implement any conditional usage for css class loading and hiding that loaded class

Comment: Did you try ngClass or ngStyle for this?