# Track network for requests

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show a symbol/message or spinner if any request start in the network tab

i can do that with

```
$( document ).ajaxSend(function() {
```

or

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
```

and i can track clicks on a href or buttons

but instead of changing the entire code to track, is it possible to track if there is a new request in the network tab

i want to track it with javascript but if there is a library or something i don't mind using it

Comment: _and i can track clicks on a href or buttons.._ Nope, with that you just can track AJAX calls initiated by jquery's [Ajax methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

Comment: *if any request start in the network tab* You can't do this. If you use some kind of client side framework, like Ember or [Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323108/show-a-loading-gif-for-each-http-request-angular-4) you could(ish). But that's going to involve rewriting your entire front end.

Comment: You cannot track _all_ network activity with javascript. The only way to do such things in a browser is browser's extension.