# Unable to detect change Angular App shell

Tags: angular, angular9

I have followed below steps

1) ng new my-app --routing

2) ng generate app-shell

3) ng run my-app:app-shell

4) ng run my-app:app-shell:production

also verified `angular.json` file have mentioned changes of https://angular.io/guide/app-shell

but I am unable to have changes neither in performace nor `dis/index.html` with `app-shell works!` .

I want put loader on screen when app loads.
Please assist.

Comment: If you want to show loader while application loads, there is no need to use `app-shell`. [Please, read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144655/angular-2-loader-on-each-http-request)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: I don't need loader on each request, I just need need loader when app launch first time to browser or on F5 (refresh web page ) So while angular load all bundles there would be loader screen or someother skeleton screen.

and there is not error ng build --prod  and ng serve working well but i can't see any app-shell kind of effect