# Angular2: Route change keep view

Tags: angular, routes, transition

I'm currently trying to make a transition between routes, using host animations like `[@routerTransition]` doesn't work for me, because the animation is dynamic.

So i'm looking for a way to prevent the component being destroyed when changing routes, and when the animation is finished the component should be destroyed.

There isn't much to go with on this subject i suspect i'll have to extend the router outlet and do the *magic* there.

Could anyone point me in the right direction, some links or even better examples would be great.

Comment: have you seen this? https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-animate-router-transitions-6de179e00204    or this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767111/angular-2-router-how-to-animate-page-transition-during-route-resolve

Comment: Yes, but my transition is suppose to be dynamic. Which is not possible with `[@routerTransition]`