# Consistent loading screen with Angular2 router resolve()s

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing

**TLDR;** I have a "spinner" HTML element in my index.html, and I want to show it until the @angular/router resolve() has been resolved, how to achieve that?

**More details:**

When not using router and resolves, I can achieve what i expect just doing this:

**index.html**:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
  <app-base>
    <div class="spinner">Loading...</div>
  </app-base>
</body>
```

What happens here: a spinner is showing until Angular2 application bootstraps, and replaces the content of `<app-base>`. Everything works wonders.

**With @angular/router**:
**index.html**:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
  <app-base>
    <div class="spinner">Loading...</div>
  </app-base>
</body>
```

**app.component.ts**: (code is exactly the same as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38620817/1071793), setting `this.loading`)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-base',
  template: `
    <div class="spinner" *ngIf="loading">Loading...</div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
```

**routing.ts**:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    resolve: { package: HomeResolver }
  },
];
```

What happens here: a spinner is shown until Angular2 bootstraps, then it gets replaced by an analogous spinner, managed by Angular DOM (but rebooting spin animation, as the DOM is modified), then the `HomeComponent` kicks in when the `HomeResolver` is.. resolved.

This is sub-par experience, as the spinner resets at application bootstrap, but before the route resolve is done.

Comment: I think it might be impossible to do until [<ng-content> works on App Root Component](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4946)

Comment: I didn't quite understand but are you looking for something like this please click on the link and click any league and see the loading https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/footballdetails/

Comment: For example in your link I can see 3 states: 1 - just 'loading...' 2 - 'Football data' header only, without data 3 - The entire page with data. What I want to accomplish is to just have 2 states => 1 - 'loading...' 2 - Home page with data (already) received and compiled

Comment: what you want to achieve is state management in Angular for that you need to use redux in your application. Where only a single state.will be maintained. For redux you can check this repo by me  https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts

Comment: But for this example i can say that that you can make use of router resolve to fetch data and by default you can have a loading component

Comment: Sorry but you are out of scope, in my application I am using ngrx for state management, but this is not a state management problem, this is a DOM-redraw problematic.

Comment: but accrodin to my last comment cant you proceed like that

Comment: Was helpfull to me. Nice link!