# ViewChild returns undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material, viewchild

I am using material design and Angular 5. I was trying to use the material loader, so when navigation start show loader and when ends remove loader as per the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069609/show-loading-screen-when-navigating-between-routes-in-angular-2). I tried `viewchild` by

```
<mat-progress-bar #spinnerElement [mode]="'indeterminate'" [color]="'primary'"></mat-progress-bar>
```

and called in my component constructor as below:

```
@ViewChild('spinnerElement')
spinnerElement: ElementRef;

constructor(
.....
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private renderer: Renderer) {
        console.log(this.spinnerElement, 'spinnerElement');
    }
```

But console always returns `undefined`. Bit new to Angular. Any idea why guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at angular [life cycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

You can't access your DOM elements in your constructor because they still not rendered.

Try to access your 'spinnerElement' in your ngOnInit().

ngOnInit():

> Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the
>   data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input
>   properties. Called once, after the first ngOnChanges().

Answer (score 1):

Access `@ViewChild` in `ngOnInit()`, You can't use it before it is initialized.

Comment: No, it's not available in ngOnInit, you have to wait at least for ngAfterViewInit()