# How to display loading screen while routing using navigation in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, loading-image

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069609/show-loading-screen-when-navigating-between-routes-in-angular-2) but could'nt get it working. I'm completely new to Angular2 (with no knowledge of AngularJS). Well the loading screen does'nt show up, I guess I need to add some time out so that it gets some time to be displayed but where and how I don't know.
**app.component.ts**

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {
      Router,
      // import as RouterEvent to avoid confusion with the DOM Event
      Event as RouterEvent,
      NavigationStart,
      NavigationEnd,
      NavigationCancel,
      NavigationError
    } from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./loadingCSS.css']
    })

    export class AppComponent {
    // Sets initial value to true to show loading spinner on first load
      loading = true;

      constructor(private router: Router) {
        router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
         this.navigationInterceptor(event);
      });
    }

      // Shows and hides the loading spinner during RouterEvent changes
      navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          this.loading = true;
        }
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          this.loading = false;
        }

        // Set loading state to false in both of the below events to hide the spinner in case a request fails
        if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
          this.loading = false;
        }
        if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
          this.loading = false;
        }
      }
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/ArrayOP']"><button>Array operation</button></a>
<a [routerLink]="['/Calci']"><button>Calculator</button></a>
<div class="loading-overlay" *ngIf="loading">
  Loading<span class="d">.</span><span class="d d-2">.</span><span class="d d-3">.</span>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I want to achieve that the loading screen shows up in every routing in whole application and the loading screen that I'm trying to show up is [this](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-loading-screen/) (code reference). Any suggestion would be of great help.

Comment: While routing or api call?

Comment: for now while routing @ManikandanVelayutham but it will be fine if I get for both as I'll be getting data from a json file(in src/app/mydata.json) as well after this..

Comment: Did u got any error?.. navigationInterceptor firing?

Comment: no.. there is nothing on the console @ManikandanVelayutham . when I'm commenting Navigationend, ..cancle, ..error ; the image is displayed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. Posting it if anyone needs it in future.
This is what I did... I added `setTimeout` functionality to the **app.component.ts** as

```js
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Router,
  // import as RouterEvent to avoid confusion with the DOM Event
  Event as RouterEvent,
  NavigationStart,
  NavigationEnd,
  NavigationCancel,
  NavigationError
} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loadingCSS.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  // Sets initial value to true to show loading spinner on first load
  loading = true;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
      this.navigationInterceptor(event);
    });
  }

  // Shows and hides the loading spinner during RouterEvent changes
  navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.loading = true;
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      setTimeout(() => { // here
        this.loading = false;
      }, 2000);
    }

    // Set loading state to false in both of the below events to hide the spinner in case a request fails
    if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
      setTimeout(() => { // here
        this.loading = false;
      }, 2000);
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
      setTimeout(() => { // here
        this.loading = false;
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
```

And changed the HTML as

```html
<div class="loading-overlay" *ngIf="loading">
  Loading<span class="d">.</span><span class="d d-2">.</span><span class="d d-3">.</span>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!loading">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the set timeout will work but it is not the right way to work as it will still show the data delay if there is while switching from one route to another route. For better results don't use the set timeout

Comment: So what shall I use? Please suggest

Comment: You can create a loader service and use it between the routing instead of the settimeout