# How to show a loading status for Angular lazy-loaded routes?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-standalone-components, angular-lazyloading, angular17

I have an Angular 17 application which uses standalone components, the initial routes are set up like so in `app.routes.ts`

```ts
export const appRoutes: Array<Route> = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    title: 'Login',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import(`./app-authorized.routes`).then((r) => r.appAuthorizedRoutes),
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/dashboard' },
];
```

Once the user logs in they are authorized and redirected to `/dashboard`, and the `app-authorized.routes.ts` routes are loaded. Here is what that file looks like:

```ts
export const appAuthorizedRoutes: Array<Route> = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    title: 'Dashboard',
  },
  {
    path: 'settings',
    component: SettingsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    title: 'Settings',
  },
  //etc...
];
```

An issue I have is that after logging in, there is a delay as the data loads and the UI looks strange.  I have a navigation bar set to appear when authorized, which shows but the login component is also still showing - which is wrong.

After logging in and while the lazy-loaded chunks are loading, is there a way to display this progress in the UI somehow?

Comment: please check this answer, looks like a fit for your requirement [spinner on component loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292393/how-to-display-loading-screen-while-routing-using-navigation-in-angular2)

Comment: @NarenMurali That has pointed me in the right direction, thanks! I've now found there are router events for `RouteConfigLoadStart` and `RouteConfigLoadEnd` and willpost a solution here shortly

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out when you use `loadChildren` in your route config there are Start/End events for the loading of these, perfect! When I log these out it's easy to see exactly what is happening

[image: Angular Route Events RouteConfigLoadStart and RouteConfigLoadEnd]

So this means adding a loader is now pretty simple

```ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly router = inject(Router);
  
  isLoadingRouteConfig = false;
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe((ev) => {
      if (ev instanceof RouteConfigLoadStart) {
        this.isLoadingRouteConfig = true;
      } else if (ev instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd) {
        this.isLoadingRouteConfig = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and then in the template:

```html
@if (isLoadingRouteConfig) {
    Loading...
} @else {
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
}
```