# Loader When Click On Route Lazy Loading [ Angular ]

Tags: angular

I'm using lazy loading in Angular Router. When I click on a menu item and the component is loading, I want to show a loading indicator and hide it when the component loaded completely. How can this be done?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    redirectTo:'/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'site-feedback',
    loadChildren: "src/app/views/site-feedback/site- 
     feedback.module#SiteFeedbackModule"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using different concepts like
1. Interceptor
2. Resolver
3. NGRX store

Comment: You can follow this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069609/show-loading-screen-when-navigating-between-routes-in-angular-2