# angular component wait for another component to render DOM (resolve)

Tags: angular, promise, render, resolve, resolver

I have a page that call two component through selector:

```
<app-category-list>
<article-view></article-view>
```

In order to gathering datas for article-view I use a resolve attached to the route.module in this way:

```
 {path: 'article-view/:id', component: ArticleViewComponent , resolve: { article: ArticleDataResolver }, data: {title: 'View Article'}},
```

this resolve call a service with a promise inside that does a API request.

I retrive the *data* for my category using an *APP_Initializer* that return a promise in order to have this *data* when the application is initialized.

Everything is working and the component ***category*** received its data.

PROBLEM

The component ***category*** wait to render the category page until the *revolse* end its *promise* and return its data.

Is that a problem cos the two component are called in the same page as childs?

Comment: This is the normal behaviour of router. What ever you put in router resolve. Before loading the component. router will complete all the resolve items. You should show a loader when router is resolving I think. [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069609/show-loading-screen-when-navigating-between-routes-in-angular-2)

Comment: So basically one component using a resolve block all the others components that are loading on a parent page?

Comment: what ever you load in <router-outlet> will not be there

Comment: the category is located outside the <router-outlet>